# Using "do so" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammaticality, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

I am not very happy with this sentence as I feel it contains duplicate words (`use`):

> UK children ranked the highest in using online games, where 50% of
> them have use them

I want to change it to this, but I am not sure if `do so` phrase is correct:

> UK children ranked the highest in using online games, where 50% of
> them do so

Are the two sentences correct? which is better?

Comment: The second one is better, but I find _ranked_ ambiguous. I assume you mean _included the greatest number of users_ rather than _were the best players_?

Comment: In these sentences, it sounds like *where* is referring to online games, which is not what you mean.  If you want to use *where* it would be better to reverse the order, like "Children's use of online games was highest in the UK, where..."

Comment: What @stangdon: English can be *very* accommodating in terms of where we can use "metaphoric" ***where*** (such as earlier in this very sentence, which unlike ***the UK***, isn't a "literal **location**"). But the noun ***UK*** in the cited text is actually being used ***adjectivally***, and there's no other obvious metaphoric location/context to which we can attach ***where***, so it doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to use one of these sentences, the second one would be the better option. However, both of these sentences can be improved. In the first sentence, the word `ranked` is in the past tense and the word `use` is in the present tense. In the second sentence, the phrase `do so` would not be the best choice at the end. A correct option would be

> Children in the UK rank the highest in using online games, where 50% of children use them.